# Installing ms sql server 2012 along with already installed PHP, MySQL and Apache on Windows 10

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

To my life, I have done programming on my windows machine (Current one is windows 10) With PHP `(v=7.1)`, MySQL `(v=5.6)` and Apache `(2.4.23)`. All of them is installed manually & configured to work together (no use of software like WAMP etc.).

Now I have to re-work on a existing project which is using MS SQL Server 2012 as its database and I have no choice to dump it.

So my question is how I can install MS SQL Server 2012 on my windows machine so that It work well with my current installation of PHP and Apache and there is no conflict or problem with already installed MySQL database ?

Comment: The ports used for accessing the ms sql server should not be the same as used by any other already installed application. MS SQL Server is a separate application, it does not interfere with the rest of the applications listed in the question  in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be running this on development then you can just do a normal install. Sql server used port 1440 by default. Don't forget to enable remote connections, etc.

If this is a production environment then I would defiantly install Sql Server in a separate environment for a few reasons. Sql Server's memory and disk requirements runs counter to what apache and to a lesser degree, my sql, require. Another thing to take into consideration is that Sql Server, at startup, will claim all the memory configured for it. That is why you may see all physical memory used up. Now your apache server has very little memory to process request. Do you see the problem there?